# What is the maximum number of elements one can store in a 2-d vector or array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, size

I tried storing 2000*2000 elements in a 2d vector declared as -
`vector < vector <int> > a ( n , vector <int> ( n , 0 ));`
but when i stored 20000*20000 elements it shows **SIGABRT** error.
I did all of this in the GeeksforGeeks IDE.

So, suppose i want to create a matrix with 200000*200000 elements, what would be the ideal approach?

Comment: 20000*20000*4 bytes are about 1.5GB. The site is probably just not allowing you to use that much memory. Memory is not limitless.

Comment: `200000*200000` is approximently 160GB of data.  Do you have that much RAM?

Comment: Most probably ideal approach is not to load everything into memory at once but do that by parts. But that's hardly depends on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: You might want to check out [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Comment: *So, suppose i want to create a matrix with 200000*200000 elements* -- Then you are approaching [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) territory,  What problem are you trying to solve where the "solution" is to create a matrix that large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the language specification, the only limitation on the amount of data you can put in a `vector` or a `vector<vector>` is the limit on how many unique memory addresses you can point to.

But in a real-world application, the limitation is always going to be the limit of how much memory you can give the `vector`, and most of the time, that's going to be limited by your RAM.

A site like GeeksforGeeks probably further limits it by only allowing a small amount of memory to be used up by any given application, to prevent users from essentially DDOS'ing their site with irresponsible code.

So if you actually need to save that much data, you're going to have to do at least one of the following things:

- Find a way to efficiently compress the data
- Find a way to use mapped memory to allocate data in the `vector`
- Find a way to solve your problem without needing to store 20000x20000 elements